# git Push changes to two remotes separately

Tags: git

How can I have one working directory on my local machine and push chanegs to two different remote separately?

I've set up two git repositories on my server `dev` and `main`. Whenever I make changes on my machine, I'd like to push changes to `dev` or `main`.

FYI, I am using git to deploy my code. (I followed [this](http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/) instruction to set this up.) I have a website and I'd like to push changes first to `dev` where my client can take a look. If changes look ok, then I want to push changes to `main` which will deploy the changes.

Here is what I have done so far.

1. cd to my project directory on my local machine.
2. `git init`
3. `git remote add dev me@myserver.com:/var/git/dev.git`
4. `git remote add main me@myserver.com:/var/git/main.git`

However, when I make changes and try to push to either repo (`git push dev master`), I get the following error.

```
To me@myserver.com:/var/git/dev.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'me@myserver.com:/var/git/dev.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I do `git pull`, I get

```
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
```

I think I am not understanding some basics of git. Would someone be able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

A `pull` is a `fetch` followed by a merge.
When you perform a `fetch` you need to specify which remote you are fetching, so try

```
git pull dev
```

or

```
git pull main
```

Note that maintaining pushes to different repos is tricky. A better approach would be to setup a branch for each (with a default remote) and handle the merges locally.

git checkout -b main main/master
git checkout -b dev dev/master

Your work cycle would then look a bit like:

```
<do some work on master>
git checkout -b dev
git pull
git merge master (Or the specific commits you want).
git push
<get client to approve, assuming he does>
git checkout -b main
git pull
git merge dev
git push
<go back to master>
git checkout -b master
```

Look up cherry-picking in the git manual for how to handle merging specific commits.

Comment: Thanks. I am using git to deploy my code. I have a website and I'd like to push changes first to dev where my client can take a look. If changes look ok, then I want to push changes to main which will deploy the changes. With branches, Im not sure if I can have two different directories on my server.

Comment: You won't have multiple directories with this approach. You only have one working directory, all that changes is which branch you are currently targeting.

Comment: So is it possible to have one working directory and two git repositoreis in separate directories?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do pretty much what the error says: *specify the remote repository*:

```
git pull dev
```

This will `fetch` and `merge` the latest changes from `dev`. Once you have resolved any *merge conflicts*, you'll then be able to `push` cleanly:

```
git push dev master
```

Comment: Aside: Consider using [`git-smart-pull`](https://github.com/geelen/git-smart) over plain `git pull`.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do `git pull dev master`. But if I try to push changes to dev or main, I get the same error I got above.